# перенос небольшого кода из php в js

Tags: php, javascript

здравствуйте, вот такой вот код, он позволяет заменить html ссылку на её ведущий адрес

```
$str = preg_replace('~<a href="([^"]*)">([^<]*)</a>~i', '$2', $str);
```

как можно добиться того же результата, только через javascript/jq?

Comment: покажите ваш вариант и задайте конкретные вопросы

Answer (score 5):

Например так:

```js
var input = '<a href="example.com">Example</a>';
var output = input.replace(/<a href="([^"]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/ig, '$2');

console.log(output); // Example
```